# Unity android build error: INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I built my android Phone app using Unity. I didn't use eclispe, only unity.

I keep getting the error message "INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE" when I try to push the android package onto my device.

I cannot find out what is wrong.  Help me please.

http://orizun.com/220138349709  link image click~~

Answer (score 6):

The app is already installed on device. This installed app has higher `versionCode` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

**Example:**
If you try to install .apk with `versionCode="30"` over .apk with `versionCode="20"` everyhing is fine.
If you try to install .apk with `versionCode="20"` over .apk with `versionCode="21"` you get `[INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE]`.

Comment: thank you reply. i try your comment. but it doesn't work. link click again i uploaded another image. my versionCode =1.  i changed versionCode = 2 . but same problem.

Comment: versionCode = 30 changed... it's Ok.  but i don't understand why versionCode too high? because first versionCode = 1 . if you see link image.

Comment: I'm happy it worked. I don't know why it was so high.

Comment: This is not consistent with http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html#appversioning which says... 

You can set the value to any integer you want, however you should make sure that each successive release of your application uses a greater value. The system does not enforce this behavior, but increasing the value with successive releases is normative.

Is it Eclipse or ADT not following the rules?

Comment: What "this" is not consistent? **1)** You get the described error if you try to install an .apk with lower version code than is already installed. **2)** You increase the version code at least with each *release* to make sure the play store pushes the new version to client devices. **3)** The dev is responsible for maintaining versionCode. **4)** OP is not using Eclipse.